# Custom startup splash screen for Cordova airwatch-sdk-plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, vmware, airwatch, airwatchsdk

I developed a Cordova application in which I integrated the [airwatch-sdk-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airwatch-sdk-plugin).
This plugin starts automatically, as stated in the official documentation, showing the following two logos respectively for Android and iOS.

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t23C5.jpg)

[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPrMt.png)

**How can I set a custom logo for the splash screen?**
I couldn't find anything in the documentation, apart from this line:

> Branding of VMware AirWatch splash screens when SDK application is launched on device

so I know it's *feasible*, but it's not explained how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, I'm posting it because it may be helpful for someone else.
For Android only, I didn't try for iOS/iPadOS yet.

### Android

- In Android Studio create a new Image Asset `(File > New > Image Asset)`;
- copy the just created asset folders somewhere in your cordova project;
- in config.xml file use `resource-file` tag to copy the assets in the specific Android project folder (see Cordova documentation). For example:

```
<resource-file src="cordova_app/icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/company_logo.png" target="android_app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/company_logo.png" />
```

- create a file named `styles.xml`in your Cordova project and like the previous point copy this file in **'src/main/res/values'** folder using `resource-file` tag;
  The XML file should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SDKBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="awsdkSplashBrandingIcon">@mipmap/company_logo</item>
        <item name="awsdkLoginBrandingIcon">@mipmap/company_logo</item>
        <item name="awsdkApplicationColorPrimary">@color/color_awsdk_login_primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

- launch the `sencha app build android` command to check the result